# Visual Studio Code inconsistent syntax highlighting with tags colors

Tags: visual-studio-code, vuejs2

I'm having an issue with Visual Studio Code. For some `.vue` files, sometimes, the syntax highlighting colors are inconsistent. I haven't been able to determine a pattern.

Here's an example of two files opened with *almost* same code.

[image: gif showing the two files coloring in different manners]

These are the extensions I have installed:

[image: List of installed extensions]

I can't find a way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volar and Vetur together were the problem. I'm working with Vue 2, so I deactivated Volar and everything works perfect now.